# contact manifolds dimension five

Tags: contact-geometry

Hello,
Which manifolds in dimension five admit contact structures? I am not too familiar with
the contact realm so any references to look at would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let M<sup>5</sup> be a closed and oriented.  A  contact form α gives a 4-plane distribution with symplectic form dα, reducing the structure group of TM to U(2)×1; such a reduction is called an almost contact structure, and it exists iff the integral third Stiefel-Whitney class is zero (Gray, "Some global properties of contact structures", MR0112161).  Equivalently, M is almost contact iff w<sub>2</sub>(M) lifts to an integral cohomology class.

The existence problem for actual contact structures is much harder, though.  Contact structures are known to exist in at least the following cases:

- $\pi_1(M)=0$ (Geiges, "Contact structures on 1-connected 5-manifolds", MR1147828)
- $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and M spin (Geiges-Thomas, "Contact topology and the structure of 5-manifolds with $\pi_1=\mathbb{Z}_2$", MR1656012)
- $\pi_1(M)$ finite, of odd order with some other restrictions (Geiges-Thomas, "Contact structures, equivariant spin bordism, and periodic fundamental groups", MR1857135)
- M a product of lower-dimensional manifolds (Geiges-Stipsicz, "Contact structures on product five-manifolds and fibre sums along circles",  arXiv:0906.5242)
- M a circle bundle over a symplectic (X<sup>4</sup>, ω) with Euler class [ω] (Boothby-Wang, "On contact manifolds", MR0112160)

I'm not an expert, but I don't think there are any almost contact 5-manifolds which are known to not be contact.

---

Update (7/25/15): The problem has been completely solved since my original answer in 2011.  For 5-manifolds, [Casals, Pancholi, and Presas](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/articles/9095) and [Etnyre](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5208) proved that every homotopy class of almost contact structure contains a contact structure.  This was then generalized to all odd dimensions by [Borman, Eliashberg, and Murphy](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6157), who gave a definition of overtwistedness in higher dimensions and showed that every homotopy class of almost complex structure contains a unique overtwisted contact structure up to isotopy.

Comment: I seem to remember Geiges saying, during a lecture, that he didn't have any example of almost contact 5-manifolds that were not contact, at least not last year.

Comment: Steven, can you update your answer with pointers to the latest developments?

Comment: Done, unless you had any other developments in mind.